# Selenium checkbox click

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am practicing writing code using Selenium I am having trouble trying to make the code mark the terms and conditions check box but it does not seem to work. the website the website I am practicing on is https://www.starbucks.com/account/create

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
elem = driver.find_element(By.ID, "termsAndConditions").click()
```

another code i tried was

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.starbucks.com/account/create")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/main/div[2]/div/div/form/div/div[1]/div[1]/label/span/span[1]/span/svg'))).click()
```

neither seem to work to mark the checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to make it using xpath

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[h2[contains(text(), "Terms of Use")]]//label[@class="option option--checkbox"]//span[@class="block option__labelMarker"]').click()`

**Process explanation**:

When exploring the page, I tried to select and click the following element:
`'//label[@class="option option--checkbox"]/span'`
however, it clicks on the "Yes, I want emails" checkbox.

This means we need to be more specific on which checkbox do we need:
so `'//div[h2[contains(text(), "Terms of Use")]]//label[@class="option option--checkbox"]'` part does exactly that: find the checkbox which is located after the "Terms of Use" header

Then I just tried to click on the different sub-elements and one of them just worked.

Do not rely on these browser auto-generated xpaths as they tend to break often when something is changed in the website. Try to stick with class names or element contents instead.

Comment: It worked thank you. Can you tell me how you got that Xpath? Im used to the auto generated Xpaths

Comment: I opened developer tools in browser, then "inspect element" and chose the checkbox. then had a look at the page source and made the xpath myself. it's really not hard after some practice. I also explained the process a bit in my response

Answer (score 0):

You have to close cookies popup before:

```
driver.get("https://www.starbucks.com/account/create")
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
time.sleep(3)
# Accept cookies
elem = driver.find_element(By.ID, "truste-consent-button").click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[h2[contains(text(), "Terms of Use")]]//label[@class="option option--checkbox"]//span[@class="block option__labelMarker"]').click()
time.sleep(3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The terms and conditions checkbox is blocked by another element, so calling `click()` does not work. You could instead use JavaScript to click it (or directly set its `checked` property).

```py
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', driver.find_element(By.ID, 'termsAndConditions'))
```

Comment: It works well, see my answer. No need JS

Comment: @GillesQuénot No, you're not clicking the same thing. The button to agree to cookies is not the Terms of Use consent checkbox.

Comment: No need JS, see my edited post. Using JS is not the right use of a browser used programmatically, it's a workaround.